# JavaScript - I want to assign two pieces of info to an Array - do I use multidimensional arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Let's say I have 3 images. When a user clicks the button on the website, I want one of those random images to show up and I want the `<h1>Title</h1>` tag to change to the title of that image.

I am also running a script that randomizes the array before I use it so then I can iterate through the array without showing any previously shown images.

This is the Shuffle function I pulled from this website that randomizes the Array

```
<script>function shuffle(o){
for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] =   o[j], o[j] = x);
return o;};
```

Here are the images:

```
var myArray = ['sample1.jpg','sample2.jpg','sample3.jpg'];
newArray = shuffle(myArray);
var i = 0;
```

Then I have the function that actually posts the image on the website:

```
function test(){
document.getElementById("picture").style.background = "url('/images/"+myArray[i]+"')      no-repeat center center";
document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "(Here is the code that should change the title to the respective image)";
i++;}
```

And of course the button that calls the random image

```
<img src="images/button.png" id="testButton" onclick="test()">
```

Now above the image there is a title of the image. In that same test() function, I want the title of the image to change. Where can I put the title of the image in the code? Should I use multidimensional arrays? Something like:

```
var myArray = [['sample1.jpg']['Title 1'],['sample2.jpg']['Title 2'],['sample3.jpg']['Title 3'];
```

Comment: Why not use a JavaScript object? `[{'image' : 'sample1.jpg', 'title' : 'title 1'}, {'image' : 'sample2.jpg', 'title' : 'sample 2'}]`

Comment: Yeah. Use json and give some id key for what you want.

Comment: Yep, an array of objects is how I would do it.  It's easier to keep track of (you won't have to remember which index is the src and which index is the title), and you can expand it later to include other information about each image.

Comment: @lv0gun9—that isn't "json", it's an [*Object initialiser*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5) or Object literal.

Comment: @RobG I know. I ask same thing david.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a multidimensional array (array of arrays) like this:

```
var images = [['a.jpg', 'title a'], ['b.jpg', 'title b']];
```

or use an array of objects:

```
var images = [{url:'a.jpg',title:'title a'}, {url:'b.jpg',title:'title b'}];
```

I suggest the object.
It is easier to read, because there are properties that you can access.

```
images[0][1]
```

vs.

```
images[0].title
```

Answer (score 2):

How about a simple, separate object to store the titles, keyed by the image name, like a dictionary?

```
var titles = {
  'sample1.jpg': 'Title 1',
  'sample2.jpg': 'Title 2',
  'sample3.jpg': 'Title 3'
}
```

That way you keep everything simple, and give each object its own purpose: the array provides the randomized list of images, the titles object provides the associated data (and you'll be able to simply add to it if needed).

You would call it this way:

```
var image = myArray[i]; // according to your code
var title = titles[image];
```

so:

```
function test() {
  var image = myArray[i];
  document.getElementById("picture").style.background = "url('/images/"+image+"')      no-repeat center center";
  document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = titles[image];
  i++;
}
```

Please note that *null*'s answer below is also perfectly valid. Your choice.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how I would call that? Would it be the same syntax as an array? titles[0] or titles[0][1] - I'm a little confused as to how to use that info in the next step of the code

Answer (score 0):

I stuck with the use of Multidimensional arrays. Here is the new code. Thanks for the help Null and everyone else.

```
var myArray = [['sample1.jpg','Title 1'],['sample2.jpg', 'Title 2'],['sample3.jpg', 'Title 3']];
newArray = shuffle(myArray);
var i = 0;

function test(){

document.getElementById("picture").style.background = "url('/images/"+myArray[i][0]+"') no-repeat center center";
document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = myArray[i][1];
i++;
}
```